# Del Dot Expansion

Tags: differential-operators

I have an expansion question using the $\nabla$.  If I have this equation: $\nabla \dot\ (V \dot \ \nabla V)$. Where $V = x$ and $y$ components of velocity.

How does this expand to $(\frac{du}{dx})^2 + 2\Big(\frac{du}{dy} \frac{dv}{dx}\Big) + \Big(\frac{dv}{dy}\Big)^2$?

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Is this what you are asking?

Comment: I edited the equation slightly to reflect the dot product and just the nabla.  Thanks.

Comment: Is $V$ a vector field or scalar field?  I.e. does $V=\text{(velocity)}_x=\text{(velocity)}_y$ or does $V = \text{(velocity)}_x\hat x + \text{(velocity)}_y \hat y$?  And what are $u$ and $v$?

Answer (score -1):

$\nabla.(V.\nabla V) = \nabla((x,y).(x',y')) = \nabla(xx'+yy')$ grad of this will be all this differentiated again ($\nabla f$ is just gradient of f)

Comment: @Bye_World $\nabla f$ denotes a vector of partial f wrt each coordinate, $\nabla . V$ denotes the sum of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}v_i$

Comment: @Bye_World it's not a vector field though

Comment: @Bye_World for the result to be obtained it must be a path

Comment: @Bye_World if there were a matrix involved nothing like the form he has, if (and this is far more likely) it's a typo and the OP is just learning these topics, he means to ask what I responded to. The question is malformed either way though

Comment: The vector (x(t),y(t))

Comment: Are you trying to trick me into doing the final step? It should be trivial if you know how to differentiate, the result is in a very similar form to the desired one.

Comment: Okay @Bye_World $\nabla=(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},...,\frac{\partial }{\partial x_n})$ this is an abuse of notation, if we have $\nabla f$ we have $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},...,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n})$ for $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, HOWEVER $\nabla.V$ where $V=(v_1,...,v_n)$ is $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_i}$, just like the dot product. This is what the OP has gotten confused about.

Comment: For reference, the equation is obtained by applying the divergence operator on the incompressible Navier-Stokes equation: $\nabla^2$ P = -$\rho\nabla . (V. \nabla V)$

Comment: I know that $\nabla V = \frac{du}{dx} + \frac{du}{dy}$ and that V.$\nabla$V = u$\frac{du}{dx}$ + v$\frac{du}{dy}$.  I am just confused as to how they multiplied this out.  I think you need to use the product rule of differentiation, is that correct?

Comment: @PenguinCy worst phrased question EVER

Comment: My apologies.  In my head the question was rather straight forward, but I guess it wasn't.  If only people could read each other's minds.

Comment: Upvoted because of spurious downvote